# Pulse the background behind status messages to make them more visible - Csharp WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that needs to give status updates, but they're pretty easy to miss. I want to very lightly and very briefly pulse the status bar when messages are posted. Almost every guide I've seen so far only lists how to set it up on hover or click using XAML instead of actual C#. I want to call a function to pulse the bar when I'm updating status messages in C#:

This is what I have and it doesn't work at all.

```cs
        private void PulseStatus()
        {   
            ColorAnimation animation;
            animation = new ColorAnimation();
            animation.To = Color.FromRgb(111, 80, 80);
            animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.4));
            animation.AutoReverse =true;

            StatusArea.Background.BeginAnimation(WrapPanel.BackgroundProperty,animation);
        }
```

Comment: Have you thought of using a storyboard?

Comment: I saw the storyboard information and it was all XAML and not C#.

Comment: XAML is just object tree declaration. All objects declared in XAML can be manipulated in the code behind in C#. Can you show the XAML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it and i found some mistakes. It has nothing todo with XAML as everything that can be written in XAML can be written in C# as well.

However:

First you want to animate the Color property of the SolidBrush object. And second, at least in my try i could not animate the pre set background brush of the wrap panel (it said it was "sealed"). You might also want to set the RepeatBehavior to Forever, to keep the animation running.

```
  ColorAnimation animation;
  animation = new ColorAnimation();
  animation.To = Color.FromRgb(111, 80, 80);
  animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.4));
  animation.AutoReverse = true;
  animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
  
  var clonedBackgroundBrush = wrap.Background.Clone();
  wrap.Background = clonedBackgroundBrush;

  clonedBackgroundBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
```

Comment: Just to supplement, if the Background is set with predefined Brush (e.g. `Background="Red"`), that Brush cannot be animated. But if the Brush is defined there (e.g. `<WrapPanel.Background><SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/></WrapPanel.Background>`), it can be animated. The Brush defined in Resources can also be animated but it affects other Controls which use the same Brush.

Comment: I just realized I changed the type to UniformGrid because I needed items to be on separate lines if there are multiple statuses, but I applied the information in Emoacht's comment to move the background property into a <uniformgrid.background> tag and the animation works without needing the clone work-around. Thank you both!